# File paths in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file

So I want to make a file path relative to the directory it is in, in Ruby.

I have a project, and I want it to be able to find the file no matter what directory the project is unzipped into. (Say the code is run on different machines, for example)  I can't figure it out for the life of me.

It seems for requires that I can do this:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/comparison'
```

What can I do for a file that is in a different directory than my src folder?

Instead of listing,

```
file = 'C:/whole path/long/very_long/file.txt'
```

I'd like to say:

```
file = 'file.txt'
```

or

```
file = File.helpful_method + 'file.txt'
```

Answer (score 10):

```
file = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'another_dir', 'file.txt')
```

Replace `'..', 'another_dir'` with the relative path segments that reach `'file.txt'`.

Comment: this works well for file = ....., but it isn't parsing when I do require File.(.........)

Comment: require File.join(File.dirname(____FILE____), '..', 'resources', 'date_extension.rb') is giving me the this error:  no such file to load -- C:/Users/Alex and Paula/Documents/Software Projects/RubyCyrusSorterApp/specs/../resources/date_extension.rb

Comment: @Alex Baronosky, is date_extension.rb in `C:/Users/Alex and Paula/Documents/Software Projects/RubyCyrusSorterApp/resources`?

Comment: Try checking for the existence of the file with a line before the `require` but after the `file = File.join...` with this line: `raise('file missing') unless File.exist?(file)`

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Ruby 1.9.2 or later, you can use `require_relative` instead:

```
require_relative '../somewhere/file.rb'
```

This doesn't solve the general problem of referring to files by their relative path, but if all you're doing is requiring the file, it should work.